# Would Annatto mixed with oleoresin paprika cause an allergic reaction?

Tags: mixing

Is it safe to mix annatto powder with oleoresin paprika to get a better color.

Answer (score 1):

If you are allergic to neither Annatto nor Oleoresin Paparika(paprika extract), there is no reason you should be allergic to the mixture of the two.

This [site](http://www.ddwcolor.com/colorant/carotenoids/annatto-bixin-norbixin/) even mentions the mixture of the two to get a reddish orange hue.

> Annatto blends with turmeric or paprika oleoresin expand the possibilities of the yellow to reddish-orange range.